# Angular 4. How to print 2d array using html/typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I know for printing a regular array with an Angular 4 project, it looks like this for the html code on this website:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html

However, I am a little loss on how to do this with a 2d array. Please Help.

Comment: using nested loop

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you're trying to do, but here's a basic example.

Say you have a variable defined in your component:

```
public items: any[][];

constructor() {
    this.items = [
        [1, 2], 
        [3, 4],
        [5, 6]
    ];
}
```

Then in your template you can use a nested `*ngFor`:

```
<div *ngFor="let i of items">
    <span *ngFor="let j of i">
        {{j}}
    </span>
</div>
```

Output:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

Adapt this to your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Mike's answer.

Depending on how you've implemented your two dimensional arrays/your intentions you can also do this:

```
// Declare a two dimensional array
public data: any[][] = [];

// Checks to see if the array contains the element, if it does then add it, otherwise initialise a new element and then assign the object to it.
    if (!this.data['item']) {
      this.data['item'] = [];
      this.data['item']['sub-item'] = {date: '2019-01-01', value: 0};
    } else {
      this.data['item']['sub-item'] = {date: '2019-01-01', value: 0};
    }
```

In the html template you can loop through the key values, values by using the nested for loop with the keyvalue pipe:

```
  <div *ngFor="let i of data| keyvalue">
    {{i.key}}
    <ng-container *ngFor="let j of i.value | keyvalue">
          {{j.value.date}}
          {{j.value.value}}
        </ng-container>
  </div>
```

The result will be:

```
2019-01-01 0
```